# how to create a comma separated string from an array in jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, for-loop

I have 2 input fields; 1 for dates and for for a time.
The input for (multiple) dates generates a string like: `2021-05-01,2021-05-02,2021-05-03`.
If there is set a time in the time input (e.g. 10:00) field, the dates string above should look like this: `2021-05-01T10:00,2021-05-02T10:00,2021-05-03T10:00`.

To generate this, i do the following: first check if time input has value.
If so, grab all the date values, put a `T` after them and create a new comma separated string.
But i do not know how to put a `,` between the date-time values

```
var startdateMulti =  $('.add-startdate').val();  // grab input value
var starttime =  $('.add-starttime').val();  // starttime Multi

var startdateMultiArr = startdateMulti.split(',');
for(var i = 0; i < startdateMultiArr.length; i++) {
    startdateMultiArr[i] = startdateMultiArr[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, ""); // Trim the excess whitespace.
    if(starttime) { // if there is a starttime filled in
        start += startdateMultiArr[i] + 'T' + starttime;                               
    }
    else {                             
        start += startdateMultiArr[i];                               
    }
}
console.log(start);
```

If time has filled in, console.log(start) generates something like:
`2021-05-01T10:002021-05-02T10:002021-05-03T10:00` and it should be `2021-05-01T10:00,2021-05-02T10:00,2021-05-03T10:00`

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare `start` as array instead string. Then `start.push` each value to array. Finally `start.join(',')` with `,`

```
var startdateMulti =  $('.add-startdate').val();  // grab input value
var starttime =  $('.add-starttime').val();  // starttime Multi

//declare as array
var start = []
var startdateMultiArr = startdateMulti.split(',');
for(var i = 0; i < startdateMultiArr.length; i++) {
    startdateMultiArr[i] = startdateMultiArr[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, ""); // Trim the excess whitespace.
    if(starttime) { // if there is a starttime filled in
        start.push(startdateMultiArr[i] + 'T' + starttime)                             
    }
    else {                             
        start.push(startdateMultiArr[i])                           
    }
}

//array.join with ,
console.log(start.join(','))
```

Comment: This works great!. Thnx. (dont' forget to put `;` behind the lines in the loop)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to combine two strings. You may consider splitting up the string(s), use a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to combine and rejoin to the new string. That way there is no need for use of regular expressions<sup>**1**</sup>.

Examples:

```js
const datesFromInput = `2021-05-01,2021-05-02,2021-05-03`;
const timeFromInput = "10:00";
const dateTimes = datesFromInput.split(",").reduce( (acc, val, i) => 
  [...acc, `${val}T${timeFromInput}`], []).join(",");
console.log(dateTimes);

// or if there is a (possible) time per date:
const timesFromInput = `10:00,,12:30`.split(",");
console.log( datesFromInput.split(",").reduce( (acc, val, i) => 
  [...acc, `${val}${ timesFromInput[i] && `T${timesFromInput[i]}` }`], [])
    .join(",") );
```

<sup>**1**</sup> Regular expressions may be a [security risk](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-4784)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a simple `map()` operation and using `trim()` for whitespace removal

```js
let dates = $('.add-startdate').val().split(',');
const time = $('.add-starttime').val();

if(time){
  dates = dates.map(s=> `${s.trim()}T${time}`)
}

const res = dates.join(',')

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="add-startdate" value="2021-05-01, 2021-05-02, 2021-05-03"/>
<input class="add-starttime" value="10:00"/>
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Only a few lines of code to handle this.